# Offset not working in SAP HANA

Tags: sql, hana

I am trying to run a simple query using OFFSET keyword in SAP HANA, but I am getting same data for all Offset values.

```
 select * from tableName order by BillingDate limit 10 OFFSET 0;

select * from tableName order by BillingDate limit 10 OFFSET 11;
```

Both of queries are returning the same result. 
Can someone help me?

Comment: `limit` and `offset` without an order by make no sense

Comment: No, Limit can work without order by and it will take default order but I am not sure about offset, let me try with order

Comment: Even if I am using limit still  I am getting the same result for both queries. Example Query :
select CustomerId, ProductId, InvoiceNumber, BillingAmount from BillingDataPerItem order by CustomerId limit 10 offset 0;

select CustomerId, ProductId, InvoiceNumber, BillingAmount from BillingDataPerItem order by CustomerId limit 10 offset 11;

Comment: There is no such thing as the "default order". Without an order by the database is free to return the rows in any order it likes. And without order `limit` or `offset` makes no sense

Comment: @ShahMuzaffar any chance to have a look on the data model / data on which you are running the query ? It would also help if you share the HANA version.

Comment: agree with @a_horse_with_no_name .. order by is important however, some data will be returned based on the offset that you have given...but definitely not the same o/p. Hence we need to check data model / data/ HANA ver. As of HANA 2 SP3 it works fine.

Comment: I am using this HANA  :- SAP HANA Web-based Development Workbench: Catalog
v 1.120.26
And my data is simple almost same as provided in Ist answer

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example incl. DDL and test data (INSERT commands) that show this behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

It would be helpful if you can share some info/scripts related to the HANA version & data model.

`OFFSET` and `LIMIT` will work in HANA SQL (I am using version HANA 02 SP03) with or without the use of `ORDER BY`. However, technically it wont make sense to use `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` without `ORDER BY`.

The use of OFFSET without ORDER BY is **unreliable** since the order could change over time (unless you pair it with an ORDER BY query).

For Example:
A sample entity with ProductID as the key.

[image]

Let's fill it up with sample data

[image]

Scenario 1 : With Order By

[image]

Scenario 2 : Without Order By
[image]

Scenario 3 : 0 Offset check
[image]

Comment: "By default, the entries are returned from the order in which they were created/entered into the tables." this is not true at all. The column store tables get re-ordered to optimise compression effectiveness with not regard to the insert order.

Comment: Hey I have edited the question, Actually I have the same problem even by using order by

Comment: HANA which I am using :- SAP HANA Web-based Development Workbench: Catalog
v 1.120.26

Comment: Hi @ShahMuzaffar Are you accessing it from SAP Cloud Platform ? or OnPremise ? HANA WebBased Workbench is usually associated with HANA 1 SPxx versions

Comment: Hi @LarsBr which means the retrieval is subject to change over time ?

Comment: It means that without `ORDER BY` the resulting order is non-deterministic as specified by SQL standard. That’s effectively the same on all RDBMS.

Answer (score 0):

I have had problems using OFFSET in some queries as well. I tracked down the problem to what I believe is a bug in Hana's OLAP engine in version 1.0.120.x.

Forcing the execution engine to COLUMN resolved the problem but then we loose the performance benefits of the OLAP engine. In order to force Hana NOT to use the OLAP engine you can append the following SQL clause:

```
WITH HINT(NO_USE_OLAP_PLAN)
```

The bug apparently have been fixed in Hana version 1.0.122.x though.

Comment: I can't find any difference in result using this HINT

Answer (score 0):

We have finally found the answer to this question. 
Actually, there are two different types of tables on HANA
First is a normal physical table which is actually present on HANA, for this type of table offset and the limit query is working as expected.
The second type of tables are [virtual tables](https://blogs.sap.com/2014,/06/02/sap-hana-smart-data-access1-a-brief-introduction-to-sda/)

On these tables, an OFFSET query is not working [link here](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3700133)
Note: In our case, we were querying a virtual table